# Show that $A$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis

$$A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 \le x \le 2, - \sin{x} \le y \le 2x+1 \}$$

I have to show that A is closed and bounded. Sine is bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$, so if $(x,y) \in A$ we have $$1 \le x \le 2 , \quad -1 \le y \le 5$$

Now I have to show that A is closed. Now my idea is to define $4$ functions:

$$f_1(x,y)=x-1$$

$$f_2(x,y)=2-x$$

$$f_3(x,y)= y + \sin {x}$$

$$f_4(x,y)=2x+1-y$$

And use preimages of those functions to prove their intersection is closed set which is equal to $A$. Is that correct way?

Comment: Yes: this is correct (provided you prove that those functions are continuous).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$A$ is the surface between the graphs of two continuous functions, defined on $[1,2]$ interval. $f(x)=-sin(x)$ and $ g(x)=2x+1$

Comment: How do you use this to prove it is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Easier:

Show that the Limit of each convergent sequence from $A $ belongs to $A $

Comment: I am beginner in this area, but my professor also uses this idea. Can you expand little on that?